# MS Access 2010 "The expression "|" you entered is invalid."

Tags: database, microsoft-access-2010

This a very odd problem and I am hoping that someone here can figure it out.

I get this error when working in a database and trying to FILTER a table by column and more than 1 value.

For instance, if I want to filter the table by column B using X and Y as filter options.
It will filter fine if I only select X but, errors when more than 1 filter option is selected. 
This happens if you are in one of the basic tables and it also happens when you have the table being called upon in another form page.

The extremely odd thing is that this particular database has about 20 backups from different periods of time, over the last few years, and the error has proliferated through all of them even though some have never been opened and saved since the error began occurring. It also proliferated across all tables inside the db(even ones that have not been changed in a long time.)

So here's what happened when I noticed the error (and I think maybe the root cause). I was adding rows of data to the bottom of one of the tables(in MS ACCESS) and pulling it from an MS Excel column which was a column with a concatenate formula generating the value from other columns. It is my theory that it copied the formula from Excel and pasted it into Access but looks as if it pasted the Value. Almost like non-printing characters in a Java Script. I pulled the entire table into Excel and found no "|'s".

**I have noticed a few things:**

1. I deleted the table rows that were copied into Access and then
   manually input the data with no success.
2. I created a blank table in the same DB that `DOES NOT` throw the error if only new data is added manually but WILL throw the error if a row or column from the older table is pulled and copied into it. Even if the copied data does not include the newer information that I feel messed it up. (This makes no sense and makes me think that one of the column headers has an expression linked to it somewhere else in the database. Only problem with this is that the error persists even using new column headers.)

It almost seems as if the filter itself has had some sort of change made to it.

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Please note that I am an extreme novice, when it comes to database, so please make answers understandable to that extent. 
Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!

Comment: Is there an example database you can upload somewhere and make available that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What if you search on the pipe character `|` in the Excel sheet?

Comment: No form of searching in Excel found the offending "|". : /

Comment: You've added tons and tons of text, but no actual details, sample data, or any code that will allow us to research or identify the problem. What you've basically provided is a description of an automobile to the mechanics and then said "And it makes a funny noise when I turn left" without giving any information about where the noise is coming from, the exact make and model of the car, or the road conditions at the time. I doubt you'll get much of an answer about how long to repair it or what it will cost based on that information. Sample data, code, and specific details are going to be needed.

Comment: I'm confused how the Excel bit works.  Are you importing an Excel data?  In any case, it seems to me you have the right general theory -- something with a character set? -- and you need to find a procedure that makes the problem go away.  Sorry not very elegant or insightful.

Comment: Please describe the method you're using to apply the filter expression.

Comment: Well that's just it Ken, I have not built any scripting in this area of the database. I am just opening a table and selecting the  Filter icon on the top of the column in the table and when more than 1 radio box is checked it will not filter. I don't know how more accurate an explanation can be given. I have scrubbed the database for an upload example. What is the best method to upload it for you gentlemen to see?

Comment: @user3490508 - thanks for the last note.  Very important as there are many ways to filter in Access.  Your method is, forgive me, built on a bit of a gimmickry provided by MS Access -- building a query provides much more ability to test and experiment.  While investigating this, suggest you build query objects.  Trust the wizards and see what happens.

Comment: I have uploaded the DB to my google drive. You can replicate the error by selecting the Employee Table (or any form the table loads into) and try to Filter by using the filter icon on top of the EmployeeName column and selecting multiple users radio boxes.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B69UIeGwPa5FcF9SV2FPWnhuTms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Still wondering if the data from Excel is an import, a link, a paste, or what?

Comment: "Website Access Tracking"?  Now REALLY wondering about the source data.  A log file?

Comment: @Smandioli There is little reason for me to filter otherwise during this work function. I don't really need to query/filter to sort the information outside of the form in which I am working. I know it is rudimentary but I really only need to select X,Y,Z employee and filter. I use this method extensively as it is much faster than pulling the data from an actual query or filter.

Comment: I can not upload any data other than the skeletonized DB. I work in a highly sensitive area and I actually didn't want to upload even the skeleton. The error can be replicated in the blank DB.

Comment: " have not built any scripting in this area of the database. I am just opening a table and selecting the Filter icon on the top of the column". Ah, then your question is off-topic here, as it's a general Access software use question; it's not programming or programmers tool related in any way. It's more suitable for [su] instead, which is designed specifically for general software questions. If you were trying to filter the data using code or SQL, it would be on topic here. Doing it in the Access UI instead is not.

Comment: @Smandoli "Still wondering if the data from Excel is an import, a link, a paste, or what?"   - The data was simply copied from Excel and pasted into an MS table.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same error message and the solution was to adjust the date format in Windows (control panel/regional settings) to be the same as the table's short date format was defined. In our case the table had this field date format defined: yyyy.mm.dd (when I showed it in design view) and in Windows(control panel/regional settings) we had 'yyyy. MM. dd'. I noticed there were spaces in this setting in front of month and day parts, so I opened down the list, selected the top most one (yyyy.mm.dd - without spaces), then applied the settings, I went back to Access, even I did not close it, just re-opened the table and I was able to filter by selection. Good Luck. Kr, Balazs

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing I found out that as soon as there are more then 3 different values in a number field (no matter which type) the error occurs. If you change back the 4th value to one of the three the filter is okay again.
So this seems to be a major bug in MS Access!!!
I'm using the newest version of Office 365!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change your system setting (in Control Panel / Regional and Language Options) for the list separator to ";". This solved the problem for me.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)